# Facebook post from IOS not working

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I am trying to post something from my IOS app to facebook feed. Below is the test I included in my code.

```
Facebook *facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:FB_APPID_REMOTE andDelegate:self];

// Create the parameters dictionary that will keep the data that will be posted.
NSMutableDictionary *fbParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"My test app", @"name",
                               @"http://www.google.com", @"link",
                               @"FBTestApp app for iPhone!", @"caption",
                               @"This is a description of my app", @"description",
                               @"Hello!\n\nThis is a test message\nfrom my test iPhone app!", @"message",              
                               nil];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:fbParams andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

However, I do not see the post updated to my facebook feed. Am i missing out anything here?

Comment: What if you try `@"/me/feed"` instead?

Comment: that looks fine. it should work. what are your permissions do you have publish_stream in your permissions?

Comment: NSArray* permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"publish_stream",@"read_stream" ,nil];

Answer (score 0):

The method `requestWithGraphPath` returns an object of `FBRequest`. So you can check `request.state` to determine the status of the request, and check `request.error` to know what's exactly the problem.

Comment: I am getting the error ""An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Comment: Well, try to do this before requesting your feed: `if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil];
}`

Answer (score 0):

Using `AppDelegate` will result in returning to the same page `View` you called from the `ViewController`. But as you are not getting any obvious error log or crashes, I think it is some issue with the `Facebook graph protocol`.

Replace `"me/feed"` with just `"feed"` as that works fine for me.